# An approximation property in a separable topological vector space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a  topological vector space.

Let us say that $X$ enjoys *sequential separablity* if there exists a sequence  $\{x_n\}$ in  $X$ such that for every $x\in X$ there exists a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$

Example. Suppose that $X$ is a TVS  with  $X=\bigcup_1^{\infty} X_n$ such that all $X_n$'s are relatively separable metrizable. Then $X$ is sequentially separable. Thus, every seprable normed space is sequential separable. Morover the weak-star topology on the dual of separable normed spaces  is also  sequntialy  separable.

Q. Any example of a separable TVS which is not sequentially separable?

Indeed, for a given separable TVS, what are the necessary or sufficient conditions for  sequentially separable property?

Comment: The *approximation property* is a well established important notion for Banach (and topological vector) spaces. You should look for a different name.

Comment: Maybe *sequentially separable*?

Comment: @ Jochen Wengenroth, Good suggestion.

Comment: But say is **is** sequentially separable, or else **enjoys** sequential separability.

Comment: Another way of stating the property: *There exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $X$ such that for any $x\in X$ there exists a subsequence of $(x_n)$ converging to $x$.*

Comment: @Pietro Majer, Nice suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The product of at most continuumly many separable spaces is separable. Therefore, if $|I|=2^{\aleph_{0}}$, then $\mathbb{R}^{I}$ is a separable locally convex topological vector space.

On the other hand, $|\mathbb{R}^{I}|>2^{\aleph_{0}}$. If $X_{n}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{I}$ for all $n$, and each $X_{n}$ is finite, then there are at most $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ many sequences of the form $(x_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ where $x_{n}\in X_{n}$ for each $n\in\omega$. Therefore, there are at most $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ many elements $x\in\mathbb{R}^{I}$ where
$x_{n}\rightarrow x$ for some sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ with $x_{n}\in X_{n}$ for each $n\in\omega$.

Comment: By the same idea in your argument, one may say that  the cardinal number of any separable topological space is at most of continuum. So, it seems something is wrong in your proofs!

Comment: @AliBagheri. Can you elaborate? It is true that if $X$ is a Hausdorff space, and $A$ is a countable subset of $X$, then there are continuumly many elements $x\in X$ where $a_{n}\rightarrow x$ for some $(a_{n})_{n\in\omega}\in A^{\omega}$, but there are plenty of ways to have $x\in\overline{A}$ without there being a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$. For example, $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta\mathbb{N}$, but no sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ converges to an element in $(\beta\mathbb{N})\setminus\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks for your pay attention.  As you 
 said, $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is a separable topological space which is not sequentially separable (that is a very nice example). But, what I am looking for is a separable  topological **vector** space  which is not sequentially separable.